# Unable to implement Change-Tab functionality in React.js website

Tags: json, reactjs

I am half-way through in implementing a Reddit-like React.js website that shows a Tab-Control in which tabs are imported from underlying JSON file. I am able to get the tab-view working. However, when a tab choice among the tabs is made, I do not see the ChangeTab() functionality implemented i.e the log statement in the ChangeTab() function is not seen in the browser during testing. The following is the code, and the screenshot of the Tab-view:

```
import React from 'react';
import myArticles from './../../data/articles.json';
import myCategories from './../../data/categories.json';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
      id:'', 
      name:'', 
      numTab: 0,
      options: [],
      changeTab: false
    }

    this.changeTab = this.changeTab.bind(this);
  }

  changeTab() {
    console.log('tab is changed');

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('In Mount');
    let tabs = Object.keys(myCategories);
    let articleList = Object.values(myCategories);
    let articleTitles = [];
    let articleDescriptions = []; 

    var articlesArray = Object.values(myArticles);

    this.setState({
        options: tabs,
        changeTab: true
    });
  }

  getArticlePage(activeTabIndex) {

    let count = 0;
    return this.state.options.map(article => {
        count = count + 1;
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="option__text">Nivea</p>
                <p className="option__text">Blue Lotion</p>
                <br/>
            </div>
    )});
  }

  getTabElements() {

    //this.setState({
    //  changeTab: true
    //});

    return this.state.options.map(category => {
        return (
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href={category}>
                {category}
            </a>
        </li>
    )});
  }

  render() {
    const tabs = [], tabsContent = [];

    let tabIndex = 0;

    return( 

      <div>
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            {this.getTabElements()}       
        </ul>
        <div className="tab-content">
            {this.getArticlePage(tabIndex)}
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Please suggest a solution to this problem which has been blocking my progress.[image: Reddit-like app with Change-Tab functionality not working]

Comment: Am I missing something here, or do you just not have any event listeners set to activate the changeTab method?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what constitutes a change in the tab, perhaps a click of the mouse, but it seems to me that you just have not set any event listeners to trigger your changeTab method. For example, I would expect a click listener to be set on each of your tabs like so,

```
 getTabElements() {

    return this.state.options.map(category => {
        return (
        <li role="presentation" class="active" onClick={this.changeTab}>
            <a href={category}>
                {category}
            </a>
        </li>
    )});
  }
```

Comment: Not sure how your css is setup and what not, you might want the onClick set on the <a> tag, but yeah whatever works for you. You also want to make sure to bind this in the constructor for the getTabElements method, so  your binded to the correct this.